How to Edit Path Permissions
I am attempting to limit/expand who can view a certain path created for our opportunity, whenever someone doesn't have permission to view one, this error pops up:

Does anyone know how to fix this, as well as potentially remove this error from the screens of anyone who doesn't have access to the path? Or must this be done manually from the Lightning Record Page Layout of every app. Thanks!
Additionally, I have looked through the path settings and most profile/permissions and haven't been able to find anything related to paths so far.

I figured it out, for anyone with a similar question.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=001328497&type=1

Resolution
Check if the affected User has access to the field referenced in the path.
Check if the user has access to the global layout in the publisher layout.
Go to setup > Publisher Layout > Edit Assignment
Check if the global layout is added to the affected profile.

This page helped me narrow down our potential sources of the issue. I looked through the fields used in my path and the associated permissions for the profile that I had issues with and realized that one field did not have proper access. Theoretically, this should solve the problem, although I haven't tested it yet as I am waiting for permission to do so.
